# Как привязать DataContext к UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, usercontrol

В данный момент идёт ознакомление с MVVM-паттерном.
Как правильно привязать DataContext к UserControl?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ManagerItems.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ManagerItems.View"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManagerItems"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Склад 2.0" Height="600" Width="800">
<vm:PeopleViewer/>
</Window>
```

**PeopleViewer.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ManagerItems.View.PeopleViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManagerItems.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="567" d:DesignWidth="788">
 <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel_People/>
 </UserControl.DataContext>
```

***При таком подходе образуется ошибка:***

```
Не удалось найти строку подключения с именем "DB_MainEntities" в файле конфигурации приложения.
```

Но при запуске приложения(при инициализации User-Control), загрузка таблицы с помощью EF (*`DB.Table.Load()`*) происходит без каких либо заминок.
Как это происходит?

*P.s. фактически проблемы для работы с БД нет.. Или я что-то путаю?*

> У вас ошибка в классе-контексте, WPF и прочий MVVM тут ни при чем. Покажите класс контекста. – Андрей

```
namespace ManagerItems.Model     
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class DB_MainEntities : DbContext
{
    public DB_MainEntities()
        : base("name=DB_MainEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<People> People { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Subdivision> Subdivision { get; set; }
} 
}
```

> Хорошо, теперь содержимое App.config приведите – Андрей

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB_MainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model_DB_Main.csdl|res://*/Model.Model_DB_Main.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model_DB_Main.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DB_Main.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в классе-контексте, WPF и прочий MVVM тут ни при чем. Покажите класс контекста.

Comment: @Андрей нет у него ошибки в классе-контексте, подробнее в моем ответе

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в том, что дизайнер интерфейса - это отдельный процесс, со своим конфигом. И в его конфиге строка подключения к БД не прописана!

Соответственно, ваш класс ViewModel_People не может работать на этапе построения интерфейса. Есть два способа решить эту проблему:

1. можно переписать класс ViewModel_People так, чтобы у него был режим "холостой" работы - например, в пакете [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) есть класс ViewModelBase, в котором для этой цели сделано свойство IsInDesignMode;
2. как предложил Ares God, можно задать в дизайнере заглушку контекста через конструкцию `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel_People}"`, а в настоящий контекст ставить в рантайме через простое присваивание `myUserControl.DataContext = new ViewModel_People();`

Comment: в MainWindow через Window.Resources задал список UserControl's, далее через ContentPresenter с привязкой к ViewModel вывожу нужный мне UserControl. Насколько такой метод верный?

Comment: @Exception а какое отношение это имеет к вашему исходному вопросу?

Comment: изначально отображение UserControl я сделал неправильно, тем самым я искал причину не в корне проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте: `<UserControl x:Name="myUserControl" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:ViewModel_People}"></UserControl>`.

А привязку `ViewModel` перенесите в `CodeBehind`:

```
myUserControl.DataContext = new ViewModel_People();
```